# formulate the single minisum facility location problem with the Chebyshev distance and linearize it.

Tags: optimization

Formulate the single minisum facility location problem with the Chebyshev distance and linearize it.

[Minisum rectilinear distance function is in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6WSE.png)

[And Chebyshev is in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8OOx.png)

I couldn't figure out how to combine formulas.

Thank you.

Comment: "miniSum" ?.....

Comment: minimize the sum of the values